# How to redirect url requests to https?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, ssl, https

I've searched far and wide for a solution to this and I am sure it's simple but I simply couldn't find a solution.

This is the regular wordpress redirect code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How do I make it so that this will always route the url request to `https://`?

**Note**: The reason this is posted here and not on any other SO site is that I thought there might be a catch when it comes to WP.

BTW, I put the same question on ServerFault and got a big **On Hold** because "I did not try to solve this myself".

Comment: Search on Stack Overflow. It would be closed as duplicate there, that’s why haven’t migrated it.

Comment: @toscho I searched SO I couldn't find anything that explains what Denis explained. All I could find were how to move http to https when talking about the root domain not a different url and not something that already contains a `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really belongs on ServerFault, StackOverflow or Webmasters...

But basically, you need to add something along these lines ***before*** the WP rules begin:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I tried on server fault and got put on hold.. I wasn't sure if this needed something special because it's wordpress.

Comment: I've implemented your solution and I am getting "too many redirects"

Comment: Does seem to work for me. Here is the snippet `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
` Just added the https always rule inside the WP snippet after `RewriteEngine On`